# Regular expression to extract based on capital letters

Tags: c#, regex

Hi please can someone help with a C# regex to split into just two words as follows:

```
"SetTable" ->> ["Set", "Table"]
"GetForeignKey" ->> ["Get", "ForeignKey"]  //No split on Key!
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Arey you always only trying to separate the first "word" (i.e., always splitting only on the first uppercase character _inside_ the string)?

Comment: I am just going to throw this at your feet: `var myArray = Regex.Split(myString, "(?<!^|([A-Z].*){2})(?=[A-Z])");`. If you want to know how it works (why wouldn't you?), there are plenty of Regex tutorials/guides out there that will tell you in detail what those symbols in in this regex pattern mean...

Comment: Thanks! Yes Basically split verb / noun. First word is very, everything that follows is Noun.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved in different ways; one method is the following

```
string source = "GetForeignKey";

var result = Regex.Matches(source, "[A-Z]").OfType<Match>().Select(x => x.Index).ToArray();
string a, b;
if (result.Length > 1)
{
    a = source.Substring(0, result[1]);
    b = source.Substring(result[1]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the regex below

```
(?![A-Z][a-z]+Key)[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]+Key
```

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) code

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?![A-Z][a-z]+Key)[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]+Key");
        foreach (Match match in  matches)
            match.Groups[0].Value.Dump();
```

for Splitting

```
matches.OfType<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray().Dump();
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z0nTu2)

Comment: Now lets try it with something like `"SetAccessDate"` ;-)

Comment: I see exactly the same as you would when using "SetAccessDate". That you would not see the same as me would be really, really surprising since it only involves setting the input string in your fiddle accordingly (on a side note, providing a fiddle is commendable, even if your answer is only working for a few limited words and not generally doing what OP is asking for). And what i saw -- and what you would see if you only would try -- is not the outcome OP is asking for.

Comment: I believe that what you are doing right now is misleading, I put one sample data, If you put `SetAccessDate` it splits it to `Set, Access, Date`. Tell me a string which does not satisfy what OP is asking for?

Comment: So much leg-pullery here... Or do you really believe OP is really only asking about just the two specific string _examples_ in their question?

Comment: Again I am asking you do you have any string/pattern example which fails? I really would like to see my mistake. Please provide me an example